# Nokogiri how to get the img src

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri

I've been trying to get the image's "src" attribute in this loop but can't figure out why it's not returning anything:

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

url = "https://marketplace.asos.com/boutiques/independent-label"

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))

label = doc.css('#boutiqueList')
label.css('#boutiqueList img').attr('src').each do |l|
    p l
end
```

This is the HTML:

```
    <ul class="itemList boutiques" id="boutiqueList">

        <li class="">


<div class="item landscapemedium" rel="sisterhood">
    <div class="image">
        <a href="/boutique/sisterhood" class="view-collection">     
        <img alt="" src="https://marketplace-images.asos.com/2016/12/23/0d664728-f484-447d-b927-679f55f24c1a_medium.jpg" class="">
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check for the `src` attribute inside every element, this way:

```
label.css('#boutiqueList img').each { |l| p l.attr('src') }
"https://marketplace-images.asos.com/2016/12/23/0d664728-f484-447d-b927-679f55f24c1a_medium.jpg"
"https://marketplace-images.asos.com/2017/02/03/f6322297-4400-4f18-b76e-66eedfc3f620_medium.jpg"
"https://marketplace-images.asos.com/2016/10/12/2d556841-7c0c-436a-a6fd-37b333c04cfe_medium.jpg"
...
=> 0
```

As what you want to do is to get an array with all the `src` attributes that match with `'#boutiqueList img'`, then you can use `map` instead of `each`:

```
label.css('#boutiqueList img').map { |l| p l.attr('src') }
=> ["https://marketplace-images.asos.com/2016/12/23/0d664728-f484-447d-b927-679f55f24c1a_medium.jpg", ...]
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you! I'm looking to store the images as an array, so I can use them display them in a view, would you be able to point me in the right direction. I've tried saving @label = [] but I'm not sure where to store that array and then how to manipulate in the controller? Thanks again

Comment: So would I lay it out something like @label =[] @label.css('#boutiqueList img').map { |l| p l.attr('src') } and that would store the array in @label? I then put that in a controller? Sorry still new to this

Comment: You can create a variable and do whatever you like as with any other array :)

Comment: Okay great, just having some difficulty understanding how I could get these images/array into my view/html

Comment: Just `@label = label.css('#boutiqueList img').map { |l| p l.attr('src') }`, you create the instance variable ang assign to it the array from the map method.

Comment: You can achieve it this way `<% @label.each do |image| %> <%= image_tag image %> <% end %>`

Comment: So I have both label and title arrays. In the controller I have created a class Label, is it something like this?  class Label @label = array.new title= something
    end or am I on the wrong lines?

Comment: Check this [gist](https://gist.github.com/vnhnhm/cbb55f85925a664e3ecc1cbb6a077b98), if you have some doubt it'd be better for we both to see it in a new question.

Comment: Okay, I've written another question just to make things clear. Thank you for the help! I'm not sure if I need model logic or something, as the controller isn't linked to a model atm

Comment: If you're dealing with a database and persisting data, then yes, you'll need a model.

Comment: I just want to run the scrape, save the array into a controller and display it in the view. Although I'm unsure if the content will be there if I deploy to heroku, then I might need a model for the arrays to be saved in.

Comment: Use just the view and controller, but if you want to use Heroku, then it'd be better to save the data, in order to not have to "scrap" everytime you need to show the data.

Comment: Using `css('#boutiqueList` is not the right way to search. See my answer to [the duplicate question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43217774/128421).

Comment: @SebastianPalma another answer from you! Quick question though, which I can't seem to find documentation on... what's the `p` for in `{ |l| p l.attr('src') }`?

Comment: @SebastianPalma oh nevermind! figured it out (its for "puts" right..? :D)

Comment: Yes, it's for `p` (instead puts), as `label.css('#boutiqueList img')` is being iterated with each, it's the way to print the elements inside ;)