# Nokogiri displaying data in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri

Trying to figure out how display the text and images I have scraped in my application/html.
Here is my app/scrape2.rb file

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

url = "https://marketplace.asos.com/boutiques/independent-label"

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))

label = doc.css('#boutiqueList')

@label = label.css('#boutiqueList img').map { |l| p l.attr('src') }
@title = label.css("#boutiqueList .notranslate").map { |o| p o.text }
```

Here is the controller:

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
    def about
        #used to change the routing to /about
    end

      def index
         @label = label.css('#boutiqueList img').map { |l| p l.attr('src') }
         @title = label.css("#boutiqueList .notranslate").map { |o| p o.text }
    end

end
```

and finally the label.html.erb page:

```
<% @label.each do |image| %>
<%= image_tag image %>
<% end %>
```

do I need some other method, not storing the arrays properly?

Comment: Just to mention you don't need to print the data inside the `map` in `@label` and `@title`.

Comment: Is there a way to combine those two arrays into one?

Comment: Maybe `Hash[@title.zip(@label.map {|i| i.split /, /})]`, but you'd need to check the data, I'm not sure if it's well.

Comment: Okay no worries, not sure I need to to be honest. Cheers

Comment: When asking about parsing HTML we need the smallest example of the input HTML that demonstrates the problem. Without that we have to read the entire file and search it to find what you are looking for, which wastes our time when we could be helping others. Read "[ask]" and the linked pages, along with "[mcve]" and its linked page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your controller needs to load the data itself, or somehow pull the data from `scrape2.rb`. Controllers do not have access to other files unless specified (include, extend, etc).

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

class PagesController < ApplicationController

  def index 

     # Call these in your controller:
     url = "https://marketplace.asos.com/boutiques/independent-label"
     doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
     label = doc.css('#boutiqueList')

     @label = label.css('#boutiqueList img').map { |l| p l.attr('src') }
     @title = label.css("#boutiqueList .notranslate").map { |o| p o.text }
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you! This fixed it, was being a bit dense there.

Answer (score 0):

You're not parsing the data correctly.

```
label = doc.css('#boutiqueList')
```

should be:

```
label = doc.at('#boutiqueList')
```

`#boutiqueList` is an ID, of which only one can exist in a document at a time. `css` returns a NodeSet, which is like an Array, but you really want to point to the Node itself, which is what `at` would do. `at` is equivalent to `search('...').first`.

Then you use:

```
label.css('#boutiqueList img')
```

which is also wrong. `label` is supposed to already point to the node containing `#boutiqueList`, but then you want Nokogiri to look inside that node and find additional nodes with `id="boutiqueList"` and that contain `<img>` tags. But, again, because `#boutiqueList` is an ID and it can't occur more than once in the document, Nokogiri can't find any nodes:

```
label.css('#boutiqueList img').size # => 0
```

whereas using `label.css` correctly finds `<img>` nodes:

```
label.css('img').size # => 48
```

Then you use `map` to print out values, but `map` is used to modify the contents of an Array as it iterates over it. `p` will return the value it outputs, but it's bad form to rely on the returned value of `p` in a `map`. Instead you should `map` to convert the values, then `puts` the result if you need to see it:

```
 @label = label.css('#boutiqueList img').map { |l| l.attr('src') }
 puts @label
```

Instead of using `attr('src')`, I'd write the first line as:

```
 @label = label.css('img').map { |l| l['src'] }
```

The same is true of:

```
@title = label.css("#boutiqueList .notranslate").map { |o| p o.text }
```